# How do I remove a GRUB?

Tags: grub2, uninstall

So I messed up my Arch system by accidentally installing a broken GRUB. I have a working GRUB called `grub_uefi`, and a broken one just called `GRUB`. I'd like to remove `GRUB` from my system but keep `grub_uefi`. How do I do so?

Comment: GRUB can operate either in BIOS mode (residing in and behind the MBR or in a GPT legacy BIOS partition) or in UEFI mode (residing in the ESP). Both can coexist perfectly fine. You can remove the BIOS variant by zeroing out the first 446 bytes. Please describe the problems you seem to be experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. I basically listed all my bootloaders with

```
efibootmgr
```

which gave me

```
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,3001,0002,2001,2002,2004
Boot0001* GRUB
Boot0002* grub_uefi
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

I wanted to remove `GRUB` so I did

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 0001 -B
```

And it worked.
Now `efibootmgr -v` shows

```
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,3002,2001,2002,2004
Boot0002* grub_uefi     HD(3,GPT,-redacted-,0x30000000,0x100000)/File(\EFI\grub_uefi\grubx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device        RC
Boot3002* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk        RC
```

Comment: So... you just removed an UEFI boot variable from system settings NVRAM, that defines an entry in the firmware boot menu. If there was an actual `GRUB[x64].efi` file associated with the broken entry, that will still be present wherever it originally was. But if the entry was created incorrectly, it might not actually have pointed into anything valid. You could have checked the boot file paths with `efibootmgr -v`, but now the broken entry is gone. It's like removing a symbolic link: if the link used to point to a valid file, the original file will still exist after removing the link.

Comment: @telcoM so how do I remove the broken file? Does it matter if I do?

Comment: The first question should be: **is there** a broken file anywhere? If the root cause was that you made a mistake using the `efibootmgr -c` command, then there may not be a broken file in the first place: there just was a broken UEFI boot variable, which you already removed. If the broken variable was created automatically by some program, you probably should check the contents of your ESP partition for extra files. But it probably won't matter, because bootloader files are small and with the variable deleted, any bootloader file it used to point to is not going to be used.

Comment: Before you worry any more about this, I suggest you run `efibootmgr -v` to display the full content of the boot variables, and try and understand what they mean and how Boot002 exactly refers to the `grubx64.efi` file on your ESP partition. Then try and identify the purpose of any other files on your ESP partition. Once you understand what *should* be there, you can identify possible misplaced duplicates or other broken files. I cannot tell you where the file might be, because you already deleted the `Boot001` variable that could have told it to you.

Comment: @telcoM I've edited answer with output of `efibootmgr -v`

Comment: The part you `-redacted-` should be a GPT partition GUID. If you run `blkid`, you should find the same GUID in the `PARTUUID=` field of the output, associated with the ESP partition that contains the bootloader file mentioned on the same `efibootmgr -v` output line. This tells you where the *good* GRUB bootloader is. If you search your `/boot/efi` subtree and find a second `grubx64.efi` *anywhere other than* `/boot/efi/EFI/grub_uefi/grubx64.efi`, you'll now know it's the broken one. It might be in directory `/boot/efi/EFI/GRUB/`: if that directory exists, feel free to delete it.

Comment: @telcoM blkid returns no output?

Comment: Your Arch's version of `blkid` may behave differently from my Debian's. Make sure you run it as root, or try `lsblk -o +PARTUUID` instead (should not require root).

Comment: @telcoM Ah root worked.

Comment: @telcoM Not only is there no second `grubx64.efi`, I searched in /boot and there was no `grubx64.efi` at all.

Comment: Maybe your ESP partition is not normally mounted? Some distributions mount it to `/boot/efi`, others may mount it elsewhere or leave it completely unmounted unless you're actively updating the bootloader.

Comment: @telcoM Hmm I don't know, when I installed Arch I mounted /dev/nvme0n1p3 (EFI system) to /boot. That's all I know. :/

Comment: Unless you also wrote a line for `/dev/nvme0n1p3` into `/etc/fstab`, then that mount was one-time-only, and would not be there after a reboot.

Comment: @telcoM Yeah I didn't add that to my fstab. My fstab currently only has swap and root partitions, no EFI.